# 'NSRangeException', reason: [__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray -> it is keep getting out of index bounds

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api, google-directions-api

```
[["The Cheesecake Factory", 3.8], ["Dave & Buster\'s", 3.8], ["Paul Martin\'s American Grill", 4.2], ["Yard House", 4.3], ["Javier\'s Restaurant - Irvine", 4], ["CUCINA enoteca Irvine", 4.4], ["SUBWAY®Restaurants", 3.2], ["SUBWAY®Restaurants", 4], ["Wendy\'s", 3.8], ["Izakaya Wasa", 3.7], ["Veggie Grill", 4.5], ["Bruegger\'s Bagels", 4.5], ["Capital Seafood Restaurant - Irvine Spectrum", 4], ["Burger King", 3.5], ["SUBWAY®Restaurants", 2.6], ["Corner Bakery Cafe", 3.9], ["Taiko Japanese Restaurant", 4.3], ["Red Robin Gourmet Burgers", 3.7], ["Johnny Rockets", 2.9], ["Chipotle Mexican Grill", 4]]
```

---

```
20
```

---

```
2017-11-15 13:26:36.367072-0800 E-Bike App[2584:1830704] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183ef5d04 0x183144528 0x183e510c4 0x102debe4c 0x102cafc84   0x184480f94 0x1844983b4 0x1848c1310 0x1848019e4 0x1847f1620 0x10532545c 0x105331b74 0x10532545c 0x105331b74 0x105331a34 0x1848c2fe8 0x10532545c 0x105332800 0x10533109c 0x105336b54 0x105336880 0x183b1f120 0x183b1ec20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException'
```

Once I get the place name, rating and location (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`) above and save in the double array and parse index and location to `drawPolylineAmongMultiplePoints` function to find the distance and duration and append or push to the double array. `NSRangeException` is keep poping up..

Anyone has good idea to solve this?

```
func drawPolylineAmongMultiplePoints(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, pinPoint: Int) {

    guard let lat = mapView.myLocation?.coordinate.latitude else {return}
    guard let long = mapView.myLocation?.coordinate.longitude else {return}

    let aPointCoordinate = "\(lat),\(long)"

    let bPointCoordinate = "\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)"

    let url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(aPointCoordinate)&destination=\(bPointCoordinate)&sensor=false&mode=\(DrivingMode.DRIVING)"

    guard let urlString = URL(string: url) else {
        print("Error: Cannot create URL")
        return
    }

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlString)


    // Set up the session

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    // Make the request


    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        do{

            if error != nil{
                print("Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")

            } else {

                guard let data = data else {
                    throw JSONError.NoData
                }
                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary else {
                    throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
                }



                let arrayRoutes = json["routes"] as! NSArray
                let dicOfPoints = arrayRoutes[0] as! NSDictionary
                let dic1 = dicOfPoints["overview_polyline"] as! NSDictionary
                let points = dic1["points"] as! String

                let arrayLegs = (arrayRoutes[0] as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "legs") as! NSArray
                let arraySteps = arrayLegs[0] as! NSDictionary


                let dicDistance = arraySteps["distance"] as! NSDictionary
                let totalDistance = dicDistance["text"] as! String
                self.totalremainingDistance = (dicDistance["value"] as! Double)*(1/1000)*(1.61)


                let dicDuration = arraySteps["duration"] as! NSDictionary
                let totalDuration = dicDuration["text"] as! String
                self.totalremainingDuration = dicDuration["value"] as! Double


                let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

                //self.eachCarouselDataDic[index] += [totalDistance, totalDuration]

                //print(self.eachCarouselDataDic)
                self.eachCarouselDataDic[pinPoint] += [totalDistance, totalDuration, points, position]
                //print(self.eachCarouselDataDic)


            }

        }catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)

        }


    })
    task.resume()

}



@objc func POIForPlaces(sender: UIButton) {
    print("I am here~~~")

    //mapView.clear()

    //For Carousel view to have access to the POI elements
    isThisFirstTime = false
    self.eachCarouselDataDic.removeAll()

    var typeOfPlace = String()

    var markerImage = UIImage()


    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        typeOfPlace = "cafe"
        markerImage = UIImage(named: "cafe")!
    case 1:
        typeOfPlace = "restaurant"
        markerImage = UIImage(named: "restaurant")!
    default:
        break
    }
    let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)


    guard let lat = mapView.myLocation?.coordinate.latitude else {return}
    guard let long = mapView.myLocation?.coordinate.longitude else {return}


    var arrayOfLocations = [CLLocationCoordinate2D()]
    arrayOfLocations.removeFirst()
    var arrayOfNames = [String()]
    arrayOfNames.removeFirst()
    var arrayOfAddress = [String()]
    arrayOfAddress.removeFirst()
    var arrayOfRating = [Double()]
    arrayOfRating.removeFirst()
    var name = String()
    var counter = 0

    let jsonURLString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(lat),\(long)&maxprice=3&radius=3200&opennow&type=\(typeOfPlace)&key=\(Config.GOOGLE_API_KEY)"


    guard let urlString = URL(string: jsonURLString) else {
        print("Error: Cannot create URL")
        return
    }


    //markerView.tintColor = UIColor.DTIBlue()

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlString)


    // Set up the session

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)


    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in


        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { return }

        switch httpResponse.statusCode {
        case 200:
            do{

                guard let data = data else { return }

                guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary else { return }

                //print(json)

                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

                    let arrayPlaces = json["results"] as! NSArray

                    if arrayPlaces.count > 0 {
                        for i in 0..<arrayPlaces.count {
                            print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

                            print(arrayPlaces.count)

                            print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

                            self.eachCarouselDataDic.append([])
                            let arrayForLocations = (((arrayPlaces[i] as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "geometry") as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary)
                            let lat = arrayForLocations.object(forKey: "lat")
                            let long = arrayForLocations.object(forKey: "lng")
                            let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: long as! CLLocationDegrees)

                            let arrayForName = (arrayPlaces[i] as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "name") as! String
                            let arrayForAddress = (arrayPlaces[i] as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "vicinity") as! String

                            if let arrayForRating = (arrayPlaces[i] as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "rating") as? NSNumber {
                                arrayOfRating.append(Double(truncating: arrayForRating).rounded(toPlaces: 1))
                                self.eachCarouselDataDic[i] += [arrayForName, arrayForRating]
                                print(self.eachCarouselDataDic)
                            } else {
                                arrayOfRating.append(0.0)
                                self.eachCarouselDataDic[i] += [arrayForName,0.0]
                                print(self.eachCarouselDataDic)
                            }
                            print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

                            print(self.eachCarouselDataDic.count)

                            print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
                            arrayOfNames.append(arrayForName)
                            arrayOfAddress.append(arrayForAddress)

                            arrayOfLocations.append(position)

                            //self.eachCarouselDataDic[i] += [arrayForName,arrayForRating]

                            //self.drawPolylineAmongMultiplePoints(coordinate: position, index: counter)
                            counter += 1
                            let nearbyMarker = GMSMarker()
                            //var position = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
                            nearbyMarker.iconView = markerView

                            name = arrayOfNames[i]
                            nearbyMarker.tracksViewChanges = true
                            nearbyMarker.title = name

                            nearbyMarker.position = position
                            nearbyMarker.snippet = "Rating = \(arrayOfRating[i]) \(self.ratingSystem(rating: arrayOfRating[i]))\n Address = \(arrayOfAddress[i])"

                            nearbyMarker.map = self.mapView
                        }


                    }

                    for i in 0..<counter {
                        self.drawPolylineAmongMultiplePoints(coordinate: arrayOfLocations[i], pinPoint: i)
                    }


                }



            }catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }



        default:
            print("HTTP Reponse Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

        }

    }
    task.resume()




    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
        self.isCarouselActive = true
        self.myLocationButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "carousel"), for: .normal)
    })
}
```

Comment: This is difficult to read. Can you edit the question and format it so it's easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the problem:

```
index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray
```

So you have an empty array when you don't expect one.

Use the debugger and/or `print()` statements to examine the values of your variables. Work back from the point of failure to discover where it goes wrong.

You really need to do this yourself, you've provided a lot of code for people to work through. If you get stuck and cannot figure out the problem all a new question, include just sufficient code to show issue, explain what you've done and can't figure out, etc. Someone will undoubtedly help you at that point.